# Question based on a continuous function

Tags: derivatives, continuity

> Let $f(x)$ be a continuous and differentiable function such that $f(-1)=-2,f(0)=-1,f(1)=0,f(2)=1,f(3)=0,f(4)=-1$ and $f(5)=1$.Then what is the minimum number of roots of $g(x)=f'(x)+xf''(x)=0$, in the interval $[-1,5]$.

Any hint or clue will be appreciated.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I have tried to predict the equation and also tried to understand its graph because the equation is $\dfrac{d(xf'(x))}{dx}$, so tried to do something with graph

Comment: Isn't f said to be differentiable everywhere?

Comment: Hint: count the number of zeros of $g(x)=xf(x)$.

Comment: @uniquesolution Why $xf(x)$?

Comment: Basically you need to find where the function $xf(x)$ is minimum, i.e. the derivative of $xf(x)$, which is the same as checking where $g(x)$ is zero

Comment: Maybe try with mean value theorem? And sorry I should have asked for twice differentiability rather than just differentiability.

Comment: minimum number of roots is 3.

Comment: @jbgujgu, your answer is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Assume $f$ is twice differentiable.

By mean value theorem, $f'(x)=1$ for some $x\in (-1, 0), (0, 1), (1, 2)$ 
and $f'(x)=-1$ for some $x\in (2,3), (3,4)$.

Therefore if we draw the graph oh $f'$, then the graph should pass through at least one of the red dots, and one of the blue dots, and so on.

[image]

Multiply these colored dots by $x$, so that $xf'(x)$ should pass through these colored dots once for each color.

[image]

(I forgot to mark the $x$-axis. It was $-1, 0, 1,2,3,4$)

Now we can see that $(xf'(x))'$ must be zero at least once, since $xf'(x)$ should achieve a local maximum between $0$ and $3$. (inspired by your words)

But I didn't proved that such $xf'(x)$ has a corresponding $f$ that satisfies the specification.

Comment: It is a nice try but the problem is there are two roots, not one. I think so you can solve it.

Comment: I got the answer thanks.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that. I just can't solve the remaining part.